# Why strtotime('today') incorrectly got 10 more minute?

Tags: php, strtotime

try this code:

```
<?php
    echo date('Y-m-d H:m:s', strtotime('today'));
```

my expectation is:

```
2014-10-08 00:00:00
```

but the result is:

```
2014-10-08 00:10:00
```

why and how to get the expecting one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:m:s', strtotime('today'));
                   ^
                   |
                months    

echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('today'));
                   ^
                   |
                minutes
```

Comment: oh god! I have been coding like this all the time!

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime('today'));
```